# How to update table from database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a database table `erp_product` and database table `oc_product`, I need them to have the same value in all records. I created a route called `atualizador`.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/atualizador', 'JoshController@updatetables');
```

**And a function in Controller**

```
public function updatetables()
    {
      $oc = OCProduct::all();
      $erp = Product::all();

        return view('admin.atualizasite')->with('message', 'Banco atualizado com sucesso!');
    }
```

Can I create an update with eloquent usage like two tables from different database?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sure, you can update multiple tables in one function.

Comment: Through Laravel? I've tried creating a separate PHP file where the queries are updated, but it did not work.

Comment: Two table with same data? it seems you are doing something wrong. anyway you can use Laravel Events to do this in clean way.

Answer (score -1):

It works, I used DB :: statement, Thanks guys.